# Getting Variables from Workbook_Open module to a Command Button module

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating the game War in Excel using VBA. Everything is working, the only thing I need to do is be able to reset everything to it's original values when the game is over or if they press a reset button. After the game is over is easy because I just save the values in a variable at the beginning of the module. However, I don't know how to get the original values for the reset button. How do I make the values from the first button public so I can access them in the reset button? Or do I need to set up a Workbook_Open event and record the values when the project is open and then reference them in the other modules? I have no idea how to do this however so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Store the starting values on a hidden sheet and copy them over to reset the game.

Comment: @TimWilliams wouldn't those values also need to be public in order to transfer them between sheets?

Comment: @user58518 you're absolutely right, I updated the code replacing `Dim` with `Public`.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable outside a `Sub` or `Function`, it will be publicly available within your project. These public variables also must be declared in either a Module or Class Module, and not inside `ThisWorkbook` code or one of the `Worksheets` code.

You could then have a `Sub SetInitialValues` that sets the original values and call it in `Workbook_Open` and when the reset button is pressed.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public player1Name As String
Public player2Name As String

Sub SetInitialValues()

    player1Name = "John"
    player2Name = "Peter"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can I set the values of those variables as being public as well or do I need to set the value within a sub?

Comment: @user58518 you can't assign values to variables outside a `Sub` or `Function`.

Comment: I tried declaring the variables publicly and then setting the variables in a sub in a separate sheet. It's still saying it's out of range though and I can't use those variables.

Comment: @user58518 did you declare those variables using which keyword, `Public` or `Dim`?

Comment: I declared them as public.

Comment: @user58518 the public variables also must be declared in either a Module or Class Module, and not inside `ThisWorkbook` code or one of the `Worksheets` code.

Comment: @user58518 if your problem was solved, please don't forget to mark it as answered. ;)

Comment: It was solved but not by this answer. I just added the columns into a different row on the first sheet. Not the best option but it works.